# Set a particular image for the Facebook's Sharer script

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-sharer

I wasn't sure if it is possible at all to force Facebook's `sharer.php` to use an image different from the one specified as `og:image` meta property.

Before now a these guys somehow do it: http://news.distractify.com/culture/vintage-photos-that-will-make-you-wish-we-dressed-like-we-used-to

There are multiple sets of share buttons on page.

---

[image]

The first one is just under the article name. It shares the article with a default image (which is specified as `og:image` meta property).

---

[image]

Furthermore, each image in article has share buttons (which appear on hover). If clicked on one of these, `sharer.php` will be forced to pickup a correct image (and not the default one).

---

They pass an extra parameter to the script which is `&img=xxxxxx`.

But opening the page with this parameter doesn't have influence on `og:image` contents.

So what's the trick?

Comment: It may be that when Facebook do the request to that URL they change og:image tag.

Comment: @WizKid You sure you read the whole question? :) "But opening the page with this parameter doesn't have influence on og:image contents." - well, at least if I do "view source code. Don't really think they check User-Agent and alter og:image only if Facebook's bot visits the page.

Comment: Just check: http://news.distractify.com/culture/vintage-photos-that-will-make-you-wish-we-dressed-like-we-used-to/?v=1&img=f6eb15 and http://news.distractify.com/culture/vintage-photos-that-will-make-you-wish-we-dressed-like-we-used-to/?v=1&img=78cf00

Comment: Yes? Running them through: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ will return 2 different images. And if you check what they return to Facebook they return different things: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.distractify.com%2Fculture%2Fvintage-photos-that-will-make-you-wish-we-dressed-like-we-used-to%2F%3Fv%3D1%26img%3Df6eb15 and https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.distractify.com%2Fculture%2Fvintage-photos-that-will-make-you-wish-we-dressed-like-we-used-to%2F%3Fv%3D1%26img%3D78cf00

Comment: @WizKid Good spot! So how do they do it then? And why image is the same when doing view source?

Comment: Maybe that look at our User-Agent or IP address of the request.

Comment: Well, that's what I thought, but it appears bit weird to me. Thank you anyway.